# How can I stack a rolling n lines in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [['a'] * 1000 + ['b'] * 1000 + ['c'] * 1000] + [list(np.random.randint(low = 0, high=10**6,size=3000)) for _ in range(3)]
    ).T, 
    columns=['id', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'], 
    index=list(pd.date_range(date(2019, 1, 1), periods=1000))*3
)
foo.index.name = 'myIdx'
foo.sort_values(['myIdx', 'id'],inplace=True)
```

What I want to do is create a rolling window of 10 days, group by `id` and stack into one line.

I tried

```
foo.rolling('10D').apply(lambda x : x.groupby('id').stack())
```

But it threw this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-092a895bf73d> in <module>
----> 1 foo.rolling('42D').apply(lambda x : x.groupby('id').stack())

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/window/rolling.py in apply(self, func, raw, engine, engine_kwargs, args, kwargs)
   1841         kwargs: dict[str, Any] | None = None,
   1842     ):
-> 1843         return super().apply(
   1844             func,
   1845             raw=raw,

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/window/rolling.py in apply(self, func, raw, engine, engine_kwargs, args, kwargs)
   1313             raise ValueError("engine must be either 'numba' or 'cython'")
   1314 
-> 1315         return self._apply(
   1316             apply_func,
   1317             numba_cache_key=numba_cache_key,

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/window/rolling.py in _apply(self, func, name, numba_cache_key, numba_args, **kwargs)
    588 
    589         if self.method == "single":
--> 590             return self._apply_blockwise(homogeneous_func, name)
    591         else:
    592             return self._apply_tablewise(homogeneous_func, name)

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/window/rolling.py in _apply_blockwise(self, homogeneous_func, name)
    460             # GH#42736 operate column-wise instead of block-wise
    461             try:
--> 462                 res = hfunc(arr)
    463             except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    464                 pass

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/window/rolling.py in hfunc(values)
    450         def hfunc(values: ArrayLike) -> ArrayLike:
    451             values = self._prep_values(values)
--> 452             return homogeneous_func(values)
    453 
    454         if self.axis == 1:

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/window/rolling.py in homogeneous_func(values)
    580 
    581             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
--> 582                 result = calc(values)
    583 
    584             if numba_cache_key is not None:

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/window/rolling.py in calc(x)
    577                 self._check_window_bounds(start, end, len(x))
    578 
--> 579                 return func(x, start, end, min_periods, *numba_args)
    580 
    581             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/window/rolling.py in apply_func(values, begin, end, min_periods, raw)
   1340                 # GH 45912
   1341                 values = Series(values, index=self._on)
-> 1342             return window_func(values, begin, end, min_periods)
   1343 
   1344         return apply_func

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.pyx in pandas._libs.window.aggregations.roll_apply()

<ipython-input-62-092a895bf73d> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 foo.rolling('42D').apply(lambda x : x.groupby('id').stack())

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/series.py in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, dropna)
   1920         # error: Argument "squeeze" to "SeriesGroupBy" has incompatible type
   1921         # "Union[bool, NoDefault]"; expected "bool"
-> 1922         return SeriesGroupBy(
   1923             obj=self,
   1924             keys=by,

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, mutated, dropna)
    880             from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import get_grouper
    881 
--> 882             grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
    883                 obj,
    884                 keys,

/app/infra/data/jupyterhub/images/singleuser_spark/main.binary.runfiles/vendor_python_pandas/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate, dropna)
    880                 in_axis, level, gpr = False, gpr, None
    881             else:
--> 882                 raise KeyError(gpr)
    883         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
    884             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: 'id'
```

Any advice?

Comment: It is not possible, because `rolling` processing each column separately, check `def f(x):
    print (x)
    return x.sum()

df = foo.rolling('10D').apply(f)`

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) (pd.TimeGrouper is deprecated)

```py
foo.reset_index(inplace=True)
groups = foo.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="myIdx", freq="10D"), "id"])
groups.get_group(("2019-01-01", "a")).stack()
```

```bash
0   myIdx    2019-01-01 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                  713490
    val2                  386563
    val3                  838500
3   myIdx    2019-01-02 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                  953212
    val2                   51329
    val3                  491012
6   myIdx    2019-01-03 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                  128669
    val2                  799464
    val3                  557518
9   myIdx    2019-01-04 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                  244994
    val2                   11358
    val3                  602983
12  myIdx    2019-01-05 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                  569513
    val2                   17418
    val3                  891244
15  myIdx    2019-01-06 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                  109869
    val2                  510154
    val3                  635750
18  myIdx    2019-01-07 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                  696634
    val2                  765678
    val3                  957538
21  myIdx    2019-01-08 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                  970955
    val2                  322870
    val3                  918251
24  myIdx    2019-01-09 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                    2751
    val2                  779212
    val3                  650002
27  myIdx    2019-01-10 00:00:00
    id                         a
    val1                  981952
    val2                  309121
    val3                  848227
dtype: object
```

You can also loop through the groups of course:

```py
for group_name, group in groups:
    print(group_name)
```

```bash
(Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00', freq='10D'), 'a')
(Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00', freq='10D'), 'b')
(Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00', freq='10D'), 'c')
(Timestamp('2019-01-11 00:00:00', freq='10D'), 'a')
(Timestamp('2019-01-11 00:00:00', freq='10D'), 'b')
(Timestamp('2019-01-11 00:00:00', freq='10D'), 'c')
(Timestamp('2019-01-21 00:00:00', freq='10D'), 'a')
(Timestamp('2019-01-21 00:00:00', freq='10D'), 'b')
(Timestamp('2019-01-21 00:00:00', freq='10D'), 'c')
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work because it's not a rolling window.